# How can i set Spring Boot properties from Docker 'run' command

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which i intent to deploy as a docker container.

I'm using a DOCKERFILE to build the image with entrypoint: `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myFolder/app.jar"]`

The image is buildt in a JENKINSFILE like this:
`docker build . -t repo/app:latest`

I'm using a script to run the docker image. I want to set a custom property's value based on an argument to that script.

So say I have a custom property: `custom.property.isTest=false`.
It controls which class a bean should return an instance of e.g

```
@Value("${custom.property.isTest:false}")
boolean isTest;

@Bean
public MyService myServiceImpl(){
    if(isTest) {
        return new myServiceTestImpl();
    } else {
        return new myServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to set this value when I run the docker image.
e.g using the parameter: `-e` to do something like this(doesn't work) `'custom.property.isTest=true'`.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: add your docker file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Externalising Spring Boot properties when deploying to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057625/externalising-spring-boot-properties-when-deploying-to-docker)

Comment: Yes i know i can do that. Should have specified that I'm using a script to run the docker image. I want to take this property value as an argument to that script.

Comment: you can try now

Comment: Please, take a look in my answer in: [docker-compose-externalize-spring-application-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62945041/7681696)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can pass this variable like `-e UPPERCASE_OF_YOUR_PROPERTY`:

Example:

```
docker run -d --name servie-name -e CUSTOM_PROPERTY_ISTEST=true  -p port:port image:tag
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.
Is it better to do it like this or through DOCKERFILE? are there any best practices?

Comment: I think you can give it when run image. If you want to run multiple image with diffrent value then u need to give it run time

Comment: I was looking that the DOCKERFILE solution people suggested. I would have to add parameters to my JENKINSFILE, then pass it as a `--build-arg` to the `docker build` command and then use that in my entrypoint. This seems so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have bunch of options. I recommend to read [Externalized Configuration section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) of Spring Boot docs. I copy only relevant options:

> - Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
> - Command line arguments.
> - Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> - Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> - OS environment variables.
> - Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> - Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> - Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> - Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

Answer (score 0):

In the docker file, where you run the command `...java -jar myapp.jar...` you should be able to pass the `-Dcustom.property.isTest=false`. If you can provide the snippet of your docker file, that will be helpful. The parameters might be in quotes (eg. `CMD java -jar myapp.jar "-DisTest=false"`